# Creation of index

Tags: sql, oracle

How to create index on primary key after creation of table in sql?

Comment: How was the table created? The primary key is usually defined at table creation, not afterwards. Which SQL are you using?

Comment: You should also mention the RDBMS you are using.

Comment: i created table with primary key initially....then after i need to create index on that primary key...i am using oracle database

Comment: If you already created the PK, then you'll find that a unique index already exists on the PK fields

Comment: Thank you @aleksej

Answer (score 0):

If you created the table with the primary key constraint, then you already have a unique index on the fields belonging to the PK; this index has been created when you added the PK constraint and has a not significative name:

```
SQL> create table TEST_PK_IDX(id number primary key, descr varchar2(100));

Table created.

SQL> select index_name, uniqueness, column_name
  2  from user_ind_columns c
  3         inner join user_indexes i
  4           using (index_name)
  5  where i.table_name = 'TEST_PK_IDX';

INDEX_NAME           UNIQUENESS           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SYS_C007838          UNIQUE               ID
```

However, if you need to create a different index, you can use:

```
SQL> create index idx_test on test_pk_idx(descr);

Index created.

SQL> select index_name, uniqueness, column_name
  2  from user_ind_columns c
  3         inner join user_indexes i
  4           using (index_name)
  5  where i.table_name = 'TEST_PK_IDX';

INDEX_NAME           UNIQUENESS           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- -------------------- --------------------
SYS_C007838          UNIQUE               ID
IDX_TEST             NONUNIQUE            DESCR
```

SQL>