# create index, Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

I have Oracle database. I want to create INDEX:

```
CREATE INDEX indexID ON Employee(id_employee);
```

But it writes -> `SQL Error: ORA-01408: such column list already indexed`

So before create index I put:

```
DROP INDEX indexID;
```

But it writes -> `SQL Error: ORA-01418: specified index does not exist`

my Employee table:

```
CREATE TABLE Employee (
  id_employee NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  surname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  day_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
  salary NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(id_employee)
);
```

Have you some idea? it looks like index does not create.

Comment: You have an index with a _different_ name, but with the same column defined. In Oracle (before 12c) you can't have two indexes with the same column list even if they have different names. You can run `select index_name from user_indexes where table_name = 'EMPLOYEE'` to find out the existing index names for that table.

Comment: For future reference - don't worry about translating your Czech table and field names to English. Post what you've got - the names don't really matter, they're just text strings. Thanks.

Comment: thanks bob jarvis, good for me :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a different index on that column.
Say you create the table like this:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Employee (
  2    id_employee NUMBER(5) NOT NULL ,
  3    name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  4    surname VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  5    day_of_birth DATE NOT NULL,
  6    salary NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
  7  );

Table created.
```

Then you add the PK constraint:

```
SQL> alter table employee add primary key(id_employee);

Table altered.
```

Now Oracle already created a unique index on the PK field, so you already have it, with no need for manual creation.

```
SQL> select index_name, column_name
  2  from user_ind_columns c
  3          inner join user_indexes i
  4           using (index_name)
  5  where i.table_name = 'EMPLOYEE';

INDEX_NAME           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
SYS_C007892          ID_EMPLOYEE
```

In your example:

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE Zamestnanec (
  2    id_zamestnance NUMBER(5) PRIMARY KEY ,
  3    jmeno VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  4    prijmeni VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  5    datum_narozeni DATE NOT NULL,
  6    prava CHAR(3) CHECK(prava IN ('ano', 'ne')) NOT NULL,
  7    plat NUMBER(6) NOT NULL
  8  );

Table created.

SQL> select index_name, column_name
  2  from user_ind_columns c
  3          inner join user_indexes i
  4           using (index_name)
  5  where i.table_name = 'ZAMESTNANEC';

INDEX_NAME           COLUMN_NAME
-------------------- --------------------
SYS_C007899          ID_ZAMESTNANCE
```

I slightly modified your syntax; besides, you can avoid the `NOT NULL` constraint on a PK field: the PK will force the field to be `NOT NULL`.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36942395/creation-of-index/36942871#36942871) for a similar problem.

Comment: I try your code, but it writes: no rows selected

sooooo, if i get it, id_employee is already index, so i try create index on already exist index

Comment: How did you create the table? can you post the code please?

Comment: I am sorry, I write code in czech so employee is Zamestnanec and id_employee is id_zamestnanec, and create index is almost on the end of code

http://pastebin.com/Z6NVDSQP

Comment: This will not work, if the table already has data loaded into it

Comment: @piyushjaiswal:  We're creating a table, so I assume it's emply

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest a freakish solution, but I guarantee you that it will work.

1. Drop the primary key constraint from the table.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Employee 
   DROP CONSTRAINT pk_id_employee
   ```
2. Drop the index, then…
3. Create the primary key constraint

Comment: Glad it worked, then please mark it as solved, thanks

Answer (score 1):

The CREATE TABLE for ZAMESTNANEC is

```
CREATE TABLE Zamestnanec (
  id_zamestnance NUMBER(5) NOT NULL,
  jmeno VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  prijmeni VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL,
  datum_narozeni DATE NOT NULL,
  prava CHAR(3) CHECK(prava IN ('ano', 'ne')) NOT NULL,
  plat NUMBER(6) NOT NULL,

  PRIMARY KEY(id_zamestnance)
);
```

You've created a primary key constraint for `ID_ZAMESTNANCE`, which by default creates an index on `ID_ZAMESTNANCE`; thus you don't need to create another index on `ID_ZAMESTNANCE`.